# Read lines from file, iterate over each line and each character in that line

Tags: loops, character, line, rust, contains

I need to read a file, get each line, iterate over each line and check if that line contains any character from "aeiuo" and if it contains at least 2 of the characters "äüö".

Is this code idiomatic Rust? How do I check for several characters in a `String`?

My attempt so far with some Google and code stealing:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    // Create a path to the desired file
    let path = Path::new("foo.txt");
    let display = path.display();

    // Open the path in read-only mode, returns `io::Result<File>`
    let file = match File::open(&path) {
        // The `description` method of `io::Error` returns a string that describes the error
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't open {}: {}", display, Error::to_string(&why)),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };

    // Collect all lines into a vector
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let lines: Vec<_> = reader.lines().collect();

    for l in lines {
        if (l.unwrap().contains("a")) {
            println!("here is a");
        }
    }
}
```

[(Playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=914a8c92dece10e22ee4c81338c5f4b3&version=stable)

Comment: This sounds like two questions: "Is my code good / idiomatic" and "how do is find multiple chars in a string". These should be split; the latter is a good question for Stack Overflow, but the first one should be submitted to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - make sure you follow their submission rules! Working code is required there.

Comment: I agree with @Shepmaster but I wanted to answer this: http://pastebin.com/6uSBrFzQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

fn is_vowel(x: &char) -> bool {
    "aAeEiIoOuU".chars().any(|y| y == *x)
}

fn is_umlaut(x: &char) -> bool {
    "äÄüÜöÖ".chars().any(|y| y == *x)
}

fn valid(line: &str) -> bool {
    line.chars().all(|c| !is_vowel(&c)) && line.chars().filter(is_umlaut).fuse().nth(1).is_some()
}

fn main() {
    // Create a path to the desired file
    let path = Path::new("c.txt");
    let display = path.display();
    // Open the path in read-only mode, returns `io::Result<File>`
    let file = match File::open(&path) {
        Err(why) => panic!("couldn't open {}: {}", display, Error::description(&why)),
        Ok(file) => file,
    };
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    for line in reader.lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(line) => {
                if valid(&line) {
                    println!("{}", line)
                }
            }
            Err(e) => println!("ERROR: {}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## 1) "Is this code idiomatic Rust?"

Overall yes, it seems good. There is one minor point that you probably want to improve: you don't need to collect the lines into a vector to iterate on them. This is unwanted because it triggers unneeded memory allocations. Just reading the `lines()` iterator directly will work. (If you come from C++, you can forget about collecting things into intermediary vectors: think functional, think iterators!)

```
let reader = BufReader::new(file);
let lines: Vec<_> = reader.lines().collect();

for l in lines {
    ...
}
```

becomes

```
let reader = BufReader::new(file);
let lines = reader.lines(); 
// lines is a instance of some type which implements Iterator<Item=&str>

for l in lines {
    ...
}
```

## 2) "How do I check for several characters in a string?"

I suggest a simple approach based on `.any()`:

```
fn is_aeiou(x: &char) -> bool {
    "aeiou".chars().any(|y| y == *x)
}

fn is_weird_auo(x: &char) -> bool {
    "äüö".chars().any(|y| y == *x)
}

fn valid(line: &str) -> bool {
    line.chars().any(|c| is_aeiou(&c)) &&
    line.chars().filter(is_weird_auo).fuse().nth(1).is_some()
}
```

Then you can go iterators all the way and write your main test as follows:

```
let reader = BufReader::new(file);
let lines = reader.lines();

let bad_line = lines.map(|l| l.unwrap()).filter(|line| !valid(line)).next();
match bad_line {
    Some(line_n) => println!("Line {} doesn't pass the test", line_n),
    None => println!("All lines are good!"),
}

// Alternate way if you don't need the line number. More readable
//let all_good = lines.map(|l| l.unwrap()).all(valid);
```

(Full code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=63908c351a8c1038b07a9edc3a30ff16&version=stable).)

Comment: Thanks, I'm a hobby java programmer and the whole .iter().filter().map() stuff is new to me, didn't had any functional programming yet. And without auto complete in the IDE all the different options are hard to remember.

Comment: In this case, feel free to read and re-read the [Iterator docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html), which are great!

Comment: I run into an odd error - I took your code, compiled, no problem so far, but with my testfile "foo.txt" which contains "üü", "ää", "aöö"in the first 3 lines I get this in the console: " doesn't pass the test". The part with "Line {}" is cut off. Changing the line to "doesn't pass the test {}" gives me "doesn't pass the test ?üü", the ? irritates me and "ää" doesn't show up?

Comment: This solution is incorrect: it won't cope with "äüö": those are the *decomposed* forms which use multiple code points.  You should normalise the input when doing a comparison, and you should be using the `graphemes` iterator **not** the `chars` iterator (you'll need the `unicode-segmentation` package from crates.io for this, unless you want to use nightly and unstable features).

Comment: Afaikä ö ü  can  be represented as single code points. Why do I need to normalize my input and how would I do that? And what is graphemes? This seems to be a big hassle for such an easy task ...

Comment: @Vega: Unfortunately, this is not an easy task, because Unicode is complex. I suggest reading about *code points*, *graphemes*, *combining character sequences* on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and you'll understand that your `String` might be quite complicated. As for the issue in displaying the string, are you sure your terminal is correctly configured to display UTF-8?

Comment: @DK. good point. I have to admit I took the first playpen-working solution and posted it here, feel free to edit the answer if needed.